# How to limit number of digits in regex

Tags: javascript

I'm using match to return only the numbers from the input. I need to limit the number of digits entered to 2. How can I do this?

```js
const numbers = input.match(/[0-9]+/g);
```

Answer (score 3):

We can match on the regex pattern `^[0-9]{1,2}`:

```js
var input = "12345";
const numbers = input.match(/^[0-9]{1,2}/);
console.log(input + " => " + numbers);
```

Note that we use `^[0-9]{1,2}` rather than `^[0-9]{2}` because perhaps the user only might enter a single digit.

Comment: I think you don't want to have `^`  based on "I'm using match to return only the numbers from the input". Meaning that if you had `ree85198` you would get no match at all, while what you want to get is `[85,19,98]`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = "1234567890";
const regex = /^\d{2}$/;
const isTwoDigits = regex.test(input);

if (isTwoDigits) {
  console.log("The input contains exactly 2 digits");
} else {
  console.log("The input does not contain exactly 2 digits");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the attribut `maxlength="2"` for your imput

Comment: I need to use regex

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to make it two numbers it to write is as two numbers

```
const numbers = input.match(/[0-9][0-9]/g);
```

Snother way is to write it as numbers with count of two

```
const numbers = input.match(/[0-9]{2}/g);
```

maybe you need to allow entering 1 number though

```
const numbers = input.match(/[0-9][0-9]?/g);
const numbers = input.match(/[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]/g);
const numbers = input.match(/[0-9]{1,2}/g);
```

Comment: I use yout solution const numbers = input.match(/[0-9]{2}/g) and now I can't enter numbers

Comment: first solution forces two numbers instead of limiting it to two and so does {2}, you want to use the solution with {1,n} for this

Answer (score 0):

This would be your regex:

```js
const numbers = input.match(/[0-9]{1,2}/);
```

**I will also explain few things that might be unclear from other answers.**

If you start your regex with `^`, you will get first 2 numbers only if the string starts with them:

```js
const numbers = input.match(/^[0-9]{1,2}/);
```

If you append `g` to your regex, you will get all number pairs not just the first one

```js
const numbers = input.match(/[0-9]{1,2}/g);
```

For simpler writing of regexes, I recommend using https://regex101.com as there is a real time tester and complete cheatsheet with examples.